# Annoying apt dpkg error

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

```
Setting up alsa-driver-linuxant (1.0.23.1) ...
Building modules for the 2.6.35-22-generic kernel, please wait... done.
ERROR: Build failed. Please review the build log at /tmp/alsa-driver-linuxant.3139.log
dpkg: error processing alsa-driver-linuxant (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 alsa-driver-linuxant
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The mentioned package was installed from a .deb file with no problems.

This happens whenever I install anything via apt-get. The bug itself is harmless and incredibly annoying. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: What is in /tmp/alsa-driver-linuxant.3139.log ?

Comment: Basically this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1609338 (second post).

Comment: Can you post the log file here so that we can get an idea of what the problem is rather than the symptom?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall alsa-driver-linuxant, since you clearly don't need it.

Comment: *This happens whenever I install anything via apt-get* sounds like it affects more than only `alsa-driver-linuxant`.

Comment: Yes, but this should definitely fix it, if you uninstall it completely.